# Artikel bzw. Geschlecht von »Spektrum der Wissenschaft«

Tags: gender

Ich bin regelmäßiger Leser des Wissenschafts-Magazins »Spektrum der Wissenschaft« und las gestern auf Facebook eine offizielle Aussendung des Spektrum der Wissenschaft Verlags mit folgendem Wortlaut (Hervorhebung von mir):

> Ab heute im Handel: **die** neue "Spektrum der Wissenschaft".

Warum steht da »die«? Das »Spektrum« ist doch meiner Auffassung nach ganz eindeutig ein Neutrum und »der Wissenschaft« ist ein Genitivattribut, dass zum Genus des ganzen Begriffs nichts beiträgt. Folglich ist auch der gesamte Begriff »Spektrum der Wissenschaft« ein Neutrum und verlangt daher im Nominativ den Artikel »das«. Zumindest schließe ich das aus allem, was ich über die Regeln meiner Muttersprache weiß.

Ich habe auf der Facebook-Seite nachgefragt, warum dort »die« verwendet wird, und erhielt die Antwort, dass damit »die Zeitschrift« gemeint wäre. Das kann ich aber nicht nachvollziehen, weil damit ebenso gut auch »das Magazin« gemeint sein könnte. Immerhin ist auf der Website www.spektrum.de nirgendwo das Wort »Zeitschrift« zu finden, in der Navigationsleiste kommt man aber über den Menüpunkt »Magazine« zu den Produkten des Verlags.

Aber davon abgesehen, ist das meiner Ansicht nach ohnehin kein Argument. Niemand sagt: »Heute hat **das** Lisa ihren ersten Schultag.« weil mit »Lisa« »das Kind« oder »das Mädchen« gemeint sein könnte.

In der Welt, in der ich lebe, bestimmt das Wort, das tatsächlich verwendet wird, das Geschlecht und somit den Artikel, und nicht das, was man stattdessen dort einsetzen könnte.

**Meine Frage:**
Ist – wie ich glaube – »**die** Spektrum der Wissenschaft« einfach nur falsch, oder kann ich mich noch auf mein Sprachgefühl verlassen und ist »**das** Spektrum der Wissenschaft« die einzig richtige Möglichkeit?

Comment: To avoid closure as dupe (which is a borderline case as the dupe deals with the opposite cases) consider an [edit] pointing to the other Q & A and say why this did not answer your question.

Comment: Mensch, Takkat, bitte sprich deutsch mit mir. Das ist deine und meine Muttersprache, die Sprache um die es in diesem Forum geht, und die Sprache in der ich die Frage gestellt habe.

Comment: Der letzte Satz ist komisch. Wozu steht da "oder"? Beide Teile der Frage sagen nichts anderes als dass du Recht hast und alle anderen nicht. "Ist es falsch oder hab ich Recht?" Das ist, was da steht.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: ich habe mir angewöhnt, alle Meta-Kommentare auf Englisch zu schreiben... man weiß nie. Natürlich hast Du recht. Wo bleibt Dein [Edit]? Du musst unbedingt die andere Frage hier erwähnen, und warum Du glaubst, Deine ist anders. Sonst wird die Frage bald geschlossen sein.

Comment: Was mir grad noch einfällt... wenn der Verlag sogar selbst von "die" schreibt, findest du es nicht ein bisschen vermessen, zu behaupten, das wäre falsch??

Comment: @Emanuel: Nein, das finde ich nicht vermessen. Auch Verlagsmitarbeiter können Fehler machen.

Comment: @Emanuel: Es gibt in Deutschland Städte und Universitäten mit Rechtschreibfehlern im Namen.

Comment: Beispielsweise nennt sich der Heise-Zeitschriften-Verlag auch "Heise Zeitschriften Verlag", was man gar nicht richtig schreiben kann, ohne den Leser in die Irre zu führen, und sein auflagenstärkstes Produkt heißt "c't" - ohne jeden Sinn, ist aber das qualitativ beste Produkt des Genres. Sie können nicht schreiben und zimmern sich eine Logik zusammen die vorne u. hinten nicht passt, aber weil sie ein paar Fälle finden, die scheinbar passen, und die Idee von ihnen ist, können sie nicht davon lassen. Auch hier sieht man das oft. :)

Comment: Es erinnert mich an "König Pilsener - Das König der Biere" ... und dann gibt es noch das "Bild der Wissenschaft", die nichts mit der Bildzeitung zu tun hat ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Da ich einige Downvotes bekommen habe, möchte ich vorab klarstellen (was man eigentlich auch erkennt, wenn man die Antwort ganz durchliest): Alles, was ich sagen will, ist, dass "die" tatsächlich in Gebrauch ist und es sich nicht nur um einen einfachen Fehler eines Verlagsmitarbeiters handelt, insbesondere da es auch noch einige andere Beispiele nach dem gleichen Schema gibt. Das war die Frage des OP ("ist das einfach falsch?" Nein, ist es nicht). Ich behaupte *nicht*, dass das Schema, wie der Artikel "die" zustande kommt, eine Regel ist. Es ist einfach nur "nicht ungewöhnlich" und es ist erklärbar. Erklärbar heißt aber nicht zwingend oder alternativlos, wie man ja auch an den regionalen Unterschieden sieht.

---

Doch, solche Konstruktionen sind mir wohlbekannt (auch Muttersprachler, allerdings aus Deutschland, nicht aus Österreich). Lustigerweise lese ich auch die "Spektrum der Wissenschaft" und habe den Artikel "die" schon immer dafür verwendet. Genauso, wie ich die "Bild", die "Bild der Frau", die "Bild am Sonntag" **nicht** lese. Dort heißt es ja auch nicht das "Bild". Ich denke, bei Printmedien stammt das feminine Geschlecht von den vielen Zeitungen, die tatsächlich "Zeitung" im Namen tragen oder es zumindest implizieren: Die "Frankfurter Allgemeine [Zeitung]", "Neue Westfälische" [nicht im Namen: Zeitung], etc.

Insofern ist es weniger das Wort, das man *stattdessen* einsetzen könnte, sondern vielmehr ein weggelassenes Wort am Ende, das den Artikel bestimmt. Nach dem Motto: die {Spektrum der Wissenschaft}-Zeitschrift.

Ein kurioses Beispiel aus meinem privaten Umfeld verdeutlicht das Prinzip auf noch skurrilere Weise: Ich kenne einige Leute (mich eingeschlossen), die im (sehr) umgangssprachlichen Kontext "das Photo" für das eigentliche Kunstwerk, aber "der Photo" für den Photoapparat sagen. Ich bin mir aber nicht sicher, ob das wirklich bei der Argumentation hilft oder eher meine Glaubwürdigkeit herabsetzt ;-).

EDIT: Ich muss allerdings zugeben, dass die obige Argumentation zwar eine Erklärung liefert, aber natürlich keine Regel ist. Ich lese nämlich trotzdem hin und wieder den Spiegel, und nicht die Spiegel[-Zeitschrift].

EDIT2: Nach der Diskussion in den Kommentaren ist mir noch ein weiterer Gedanke gekommen: Sobald sich der Artikel "die" einmal durchgesetzt hat, ist es schwierig, sich wieder von ihm zu trennen, da er auch ein Unterscheidungsmerkmal darstellt: Änlich wie bei dem Photoapparat kann ich nämlich ziemlich zeitsparend sagen "Ich würde gerne die Spektrum/Bild lesen." Verwechselung mit dem Ablesen eines Spektrometers/Bildes ist von vornherein ausgeschlossen, sehr praktisch!

Comment: Die Zeitung, die du als Beispiel anführst, hat ja auch den offiziellen Namen »Bildzeitung«, daher verwundert es nicht, das die Kurzform »Bild« das Genus der Langform beibehält.

Comment: Das stimmt, daran hatte ich nicht gedacht. Insofern fällt sie in die gleiche Kategorie wie die Frankfurter Allgemeine. Allerdings wird der offizielle Name selbst in der hauseigenen Werbung (zumindest meistens) nicht benutzt. Ich denke trotzdem, dass es sich um dasselbe Prinzip handelt. "Bild der Frau", "Bild der Wissenschaft", etc. haben diese Langform nicht (oder!?), und trotzdem behält man (oder zumindest behalten die meisten) den Artikel "die" bei.

Comment: Darüber hinaus zwingt mich niemand dazu, »Zeitschrift« anzuhängen. Ich sehe das Druckwerk eher als »Magazin« (so wie es ja auf der verlagseigenen Homepage auch steht). Wie kommt das »Spektrum der Wissenschaft-Magazin« zu einem weiblichen Artikel?

Comment: Natürlich, Sprache entwickelt sich und ist kein Zwang. Auch bei der "Geschlechtsfindung" von Lehnwörtern gibt es keinen Zwang, welche Regel (Geschlecht der Übersetzung, eines ähnlich klingenden Wortes, etc.) zu verwenden ist, und trotzdem bilden sich nach einiger Zeit (manchmal durch lokales Sprachempfinden regional verschiedene) Muster heraus. Wäre interessant zu wissen, ob Österreicher im Fall der "Spektrum" allgemein eher "das" als richtig empfinden. Ich denke immer noch, dass das Magazin über einen Weg wie den in der Antwort dargestellten zum weiblichen Artikel gekommen ist.

Comment: Ich bin Österreicher, und kenne niemanden, der »die Spektrum« sagt. Ich kenne auch niemanden in meiner Altersgruppe (ich bin 49), der »die Bravo« sagt wenn er/sie die bekannte Jugendzeitschrifft meint. Für meine Generation war und ist das »das Bravo«. Wobei »bravo« für sich ja kein Nomen ist (sondern ein italienisches Adjektiv) und man hier als Name einer Zeitschrift jedes beliebige Geschlecht argumentieren könnte. Ebenso beim Getränk »Cola«, das in Österreich »das Cola« ist. Aber das alles trifft auf das »Spektrum« nicht zu. Ebensowenig übrigens wie auf den bereits erwähnten »Spiegel«.

Comment: Ja, daher hatte ich die Österreicher ja überhaupt angesprochen. Interessant. Ich wage zu behaupten, in Deutschland (zumindest Mittel- und Nord-) ist "die Bravo" sehr viel verbreiteter... Scheint also alles auf regionale Unterschiede im Sprachempfinden hinauszulaufen.

Comment: Hier (Südwesten, Pfalz ~ Nord-BW) sagt man auch "die Bravo". Übrigens +1 für den Unterschied zwischen "der Photo - das Photo". Ich kenne noch "das Radio" = "das Radioprogramm", "der Radio" = "das Radiogerät".

Comment: Werfe mich mal als zusätzlichen Datenpunkt in diese Erhebung: östliches Österreich (NÖ/W), ich sage "das Spektrum [der Wissenschaft]", und bisher habe ich auch im Freundeskreis noch niemanden "die" sagen gehört.

Comment: Der Trierische Volksfreund heißt **der** Trierische Volksfreund und nicht **die** Trierische Volksfreund (-Zeitung, (es ist eine klassische Zeitung, kein Magazin oder Heft)). Die Artikel werden gemacht aber gerade bei Unsicherheit, bei neuen Artikeln nicht bewusstlos, sondern bewusst - nur eben mit vermuteten Regeln derjenigen, die sie benutzen, die aber oft falsch sind. Qua Diskussion Bewusstsein über falsche Regeln zu schaffen gehört also zum Prozess einer guten Sprachfindung dazu.

Comment: @userunknown... die Sprache in Deutschland hat sich da bereits gefunden. Es ist "die Bravo" genauso wie es "die Cola" ist. Da braucht man garnicht zu diskutieren. Was ist so schwer daran zu akzeptieren, dass Deutsch und Österreichisch es hier halt mal anders machen. Ich gehe ja auch nicht zu einem Holländer und sage ihm, wie er sein "ge" zu verwenden hat. Und Artikel werden nicht gemacht sondern genommen. Und zwar in gesprochener Sprache schnell. Das funktinoiert wie werbebeeinflusste Produktentscheidung. Mit "bewusst" hat das wenig zu tun.

Comment: @Emanuel: Falsch. Beim Begriff "Blog" hatte sich auch rasch ein Artikel gefunden - wahrscheinlich auch aufgrund falscher Sprachtheorie (dass engl. Wörter, die ja kein Geschlecht haben, im Deutschen automatisch sächlich sein müssten), und als das Wort populärer wurde bekam es ein anderes Geschlecht - der Blog. Huberts Frage zeigt auch, dass es nicht für jeden immer ein unbewusster Vorgang ist, sonst wäre er ja nicht darüber gestolpert.

Comment: @userunknown ... der Punkt ist doch, das Hubert aus Österreich kommt. Da ist es so, in Deutschland ist es anders. Er sagt nun "Ich hab' Recht, ihr macht es alle falsch", so kommt sein letzter Absatz zumindest bei mir an. Und warum ist denn Blog männlich geworden? Wahrscheinlich weil es wie Block" klingt. Das ist wohl kaum eine bewusste Entscheidung.

Answer (score 2):

"Spektrum der Wissenschaft" ist in diesem Fall keine normale Nominalphrase mit einem Genitiv, sondern ein Name. Das wird auch mittels der Anführungsstrichelchen markiert.
Da es ein Name ist, muss man einen Artikel zuweisen, und der kommt zumeist, von der Kategorie, der "benamtes" Subjekt angehörig ist.
Nun gibt es nicht immer nur genau eine Kategorie. Bei "Cola" gibt es zum Beispiel "die Limonade" und "das Getränk" und beides macht gleich viel Sinn, und es ist somit nicht verwunderlich, dass es verschiedene Versionen gibt.
Im Fall der "Spektrum der Wissenschaft" gibt es "die Zeitung" und "die Zeitschrift" auf der einen Seite und "das Magazin" und "das Journal" auf der anderen. Und wieder macht beides Sinn.
Wenn sich nun der Verlag spezielle Mühe gibt, sich als einer der Typen im kollektiven Gedächtnis zu verankern, dann wird einfach der Artikel genommen, der im Normalfall genommen wird und das ist in Deutschland "die". Die Menschen sind "die" gewohnt und es gibt zahlreiche Beispiele sogar in der Werbung. Es spielt dabei keine Rolle, ob es eine Zeitschrift oder ein Magazin ist. Die gegeneinander abzugrenzen ist sowieso nur begrenzt möglich und dem Normalverbraucher egal. Niemand wird erst auf die Internetseite gucken, was der Verlag schreibt, was das jetzt ist. Man nimmt einfach den Artikel, den man sonst auch in diesem Kontext nimmt.
Die Werbung sagt "Die neue Hörzu" oder "die neue Joy" oder "die neue Bravo". Und so wird das Pattern verankert und dann auch benutzt. Ein Gegenbeispiel wäre "der Playboy". Da wäre mal interessant, ob es wirklich wegen "boy" ist oder weil der Verlag dazu beigetragen hat.

TLDR:

Es ist "die", weil es in Deutschland in diesem Kontext, auch unterstützt von der Werbung nun mal der Normalfall ist. Damit ist es in Deutschland richtig und "das" ist falsch, weil es falsch klingt.

Natürlich kann es sein, dass es in Österreich anders ist. "Das Bravo" klingt für mich absurd, aber ich bin sicher, dass für dich "die Bravo" genauso falsch klingt. Da hat einer Recht und keins ist besser oder schlechter, sondern einfach nur anders.

Comment: Ist das in Deutschland schon üblich, dass Nominalphrasen, die als Name verwendet werden, sich von ihrer grammatikalischen Herkunft abkoppeln? Das ist mir im österreichischen Deutsch nämlich nie untergekommen.

Comment: Ansonsten: aus dem österreichischen Zeitungs- und Zeitschriftenmarkt: "der Standard" (der Artikel ist offizieller Teil des Namens), das "Profil", das "Format", und, wie vermutet, das "Bravo".

Comment: Eine wirklich hahnebüchene Argumentation! Weil die Leute den falschen Artikeln verwenden schließt Du, dass es sie gar nicht intessiert, ob sie ein Magazin oder eine Zeitung kaufen - sie sind auch zu doof das zu sehen, wenn sie draufschauen? Das ist doch unsäglich! Es würde Dir in den Kram Deiner Argumentation passen, wenn es so wäre, obwohl Du mit dem Playboy selbst ein Gegenbeispiel im Petto hast, aber was nicht sein darf, das kann nicht sein - also Augen zu und durch? Der Trierische Volksfreund ist auch eine Zeitung. Der Morgen. Der Standard. Der Prüllinger Bote. Der Tagesspiegel.

Comment: @userunknown... ich sehe das Problem nicht. Für alle deine Beispiele sagt man halt "Ich kaufe den..." obgleich ich nur den Tagesspiegel kenne. Ich verstehe nicht, warum ihr hier in den Kategorien "richtig" und "falsch" denkt. Wenn alle Deutschen Jugendlichen "die Bravo" sagen, dann ist das für diesen Sprachraum richtig. Ende der Diskussion. Da kann man noch so sehr mit seinem Österreichischen Sprachgefühl oder Logik argumentieren. Es ist nicht relevant. Genausowenig wie es relevant ist, dass "weil" eigentlich subordinierend ist. Wenn alle es anders machen, dann ist es offenbar nicht mehr so.

Comment: Ich habe mit meiner Ansicht lediglich versucht, darzulegen, wie Leute dazu kommen könnten, "die" zu verwenden, nämlich wenn sie keinen Anhaltspunkt haben (und die Frage ob etwas technisch gesehen ein Magazin oder eine Zeitschrift ist, spielt keine Rolle). Und wenn man irgendwo lernt, dass das "Magazin der Wissenschaft" gerne als "das" bezeichnet werden möchte, okay, dann mach ich das halt. Oder auch nicht. Je nachdem, wie ich Bock hab' und was die Merhheit macht. Das ist wahrlich kein Gebiet, das durch Regeln vereinheitlicht werden müsste.

Comment: @Emanuel: Was den Status Quo betrifft hasts Du fast recht. Wenn alle "die Spektrum d. W." sagen würden - sagen aber nicht alle, wie Du am Protest ja unschwer merken kannst. Und zweitens: Die Sprache hat ja nicht nur eine Vergangenheit sondern auch eine Zukunft. Wenn Du Änderungen nicht verbieten willst (und kannst) ist auch eine rationale Diskussion erlaubt die Mythen als solche offenlegt. Vor ca. 100 Jahren hat ein Sprachbesessener Fremdwöter en Gros eingedeutscht und ein Teil seiner Vorschläge ist schlicht vergessen, ein anderer existiert nur als Kuriosum (Gesichtserker) aber ein kl. Teil...

Comment: ... wird tatsächliche verwendet. Wenn es keine Regeln gibt, sondern nur Praxis - wieso soll man nicht zu einer Praxis finden, die Regeln hat?

Comment: Eben hast Du noch geschrieben, das niemand schaut, wie der Verlag selbst sein Produkt nennt - jetzt ist es Deine Regel danach zu gehen. Dementierst aber, dass es Regeln braucht. Neue Regel: Was die Mehrheit macht. Wäre das so, würde die Minderheit ja rasch verschwinden - tut sie aber nicht. Das Fazit des Ganzen ist, dass für manche Fälle dies gilt und für jene das, und dass das Hantieren mit Regeln ein Betrug ist, wenn willkürlich bleibt, wann welche der Regeln gilt - das sind dann keine Regeln sondern nur gescheiterte Versuche eine zu finden.

Comment: @userunknown... nein, ich will Änderungen nicht verbieten. Aber ich sehe keinen Grund dafür Deutschland-Deutsch und Österreich-Deutsch zu vereinheitlichen und ich würde auch nie auf die Idee kommen, zu sagen, dass "das Cola" falsch ist, weil es meinem Sprachgefühl widerspricht. Wenn das in Ö. so ist, dann ist das da halt so. Ich könnte dann hier genauso eine Frage stellen "Warum 'das Cola'" wo ich dann, wie Hubert es tut, reinschreibe "Klingt falsch. Ist es falsch oder hab ich recht?". Und dann sagen wir "Es muss die Cola sein" und dann sagen alle Östrreicher "Ja, ergibt Sinn. Machen wir so"??

Comment: Ach so - Cola? Ich war noch oder wieder bei dem "Spektrum der Wissenschaft". Von mir aus sag "das Cola", da habe ich gar nichts gegen. :)